# Eight Colors story identification

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

The story peripherally involves a corporation named Eight Colors, but also includes a plot about people living underground, viewing the surface through prisms and periscopes. Near the end the protagonist takes a group of people to the underground community, where they are psychoanalyzed, and their emotions are encoded on shifting color badges they wear on their shirts or sleeves, i.e., literally wearing their feelings on their sleeves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you are thinking of [Marion Zimmer Bradley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marion_Zimmer_Bradley)'s novel [*The Colors of Space*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eight+colors%22+%22corporation%22), which features the "Eight Colors Transshipping Corporation?"

See also the question [Searching an unknown type of color in space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91721/searching-an-unknown-type-of-color-in-space) and its accepted answer.

Comment: Fantastic!  I just reread the story and all my memories of it came rushing back!  What a wonderful present.  thanks so much!

Comment: I don't recall the coporation, but Prodigal Sun by Philip E.High has an underground world. It's not their emotions on their sleeves though, but their psychological profile. So if someone is dishonest, everyone knows to be careful around him. One girl is promiscuous, and the man who is attracted to her is shocked by her symbols.